# Not able to connect to shiny app from other machine through the IP address and given port

Tags: r, shiny

Not able to connect to shiny app from other machine through the IP address and given port.

I hosted the app on my local machine but is not able to access from other machine using the IP of my machine and defined port.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while searching for how to run a shiny app from console.

Had to escape the " 
also: nominating the port number instead of allowing shiny to choose a random port.

nohup R -e "shiny::runApp(appDir = '/path/to/app/dir/', port = 4000, host=\"0.0.0.0\")"  &

the nohup and & allow the shiny app to keep running after the shell is closed.

there are better ways for a more permanent/monitored running service.